# Defender for cloud: Enable agentless scanning and endpoint protection using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-defender

can we enable agentless scanning and endpoint protection using powershell.
And can we configure AMA in defender for sql settings using powershell.

Also using powershell can we get existing agentless scanning, endpoint protection, log analytics agent configurations for defender for servers

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/enable-agentless-scanning-vms

And: https://theitbros.com/managing-windows-defender-using-powershell/

Yes, here are some example commands:

- Get a list of the current configurations `Get-MpPreference`
- Get details for each configuration `Get-MpComputerStatus`

Please see the links above which have more guidance, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Defender for Cloud PS CLI to enable agentless scanning when enabling  CSPM premium (CloudPosture Standard / Servers P2).
Just enable the relevant bundle and dont specify the enabled extensions. By default it will enable agentless scanning.